# Passing multiple lists with variable length as a parameter to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, args

How can I pass multiple lists with variable length as a parameter to function in python?

```
def fu(n_inp,n_out,buswidthin,buswidthout,*inpname,*outname):
    for i in range(n_inp):
        inputname=inpname[i]
        buswidth_in=buswidthin
    for i in range(n_out):
        outputname=outname[i]
        buswidth_out=buswidthout

fu(2,2,512,512,*['pktin1.txt','pktin2.txt'],*['pktout1.txt','pktout2.txt'])
```

Comment: From you code example it's not 100% clear what are you planning to do with arguments. General answer - it won't work, but to offer you something instead we need to know how are you planning to use arguments.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but you may try with `def fu(*args)`!

Comment: You can just pass the list without those `*`. In any case, what you're doing inside the function seems absurd. You are iterating over the full length of lists only to store the last value in lists in separate variables.

Comment: Could you provide more info about your question? Do you want to pass different number of arguments or pass same number of arguments but list that may have different number of elements? Also you can loop over list without taking any length information outside of the function.

Comment: I want to parse over two different lists one which contains input file names and other which contains output file names, the store their value one by one which will be further used in another function inside it and there could be any number of input and output file names

Answer (score 0):

If you input and output files should match, you can pass into a function tuples each contains input and output filenames:

```
def func1(arg1, arg2, *files):
    for input_file, output_file in files:
        ...
# USAGE
func1(1, 2, *zip(["input_1.txt", "input_2.txt"], ["output_1.txt", "output_2.txt"]))
func1(3, 4, ("input_1.txt", "output_1.txt"), ("input_2.txt", "output_2.txt"))
func1(5, 6, *{"input_1.txt": "output_1.txt", "input_2.txt": "output_1.txt"}.items())
```

But you don't really need packing arguments here:

```
def func2(arg1, arg2, files):
    for input_file, output_file in files:
        ...
# USAGE
func2(1, 2, zip(["input_1.txt", "input_2.txt"], ["output_1.txt", "output_2.txt"]))
func2(3, 4, (("input_1.txt", "output_1.txt"), ("input_2.txt", "output_2.txt")))
func2(5, 6, {"input_1.txt": "output_1.txt", "input_2.txt": "output_1.txt"}.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use positional arguments:

```
def fu(n_inp,n_out,buswidthin,inpname, outname):
    for i in range(n_inp):
        inputname=inpname[i]
        buswidth_in=buswidthin
    for i in range(n_out):
        outputname=outname[i]
        buswidth_out=buswidthout

inpname = ['pktin1.txt','pktin2.txt']
outname = ['pktout1.txt','pktout2.txt']
fu(2,2,512,512, inpname, outname ])
```